# python pygame pause function

Tags: python, pygame, pause

I am beginner and have a problem with my code. Here you can see a short excerpt of my code.

It's a simple snake game I created but I was trying to add a pause. I got it but when I start the pause I am not able to close it.

Possibly there is a basic mistake in my code so I couldn't advance. I hope you can help me.

Thank you in advance!

```py
def checkquit(e):
    running = True
    pause = False
    for ev in e:
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit(0)
            running = True

        if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            quit(0)
            running = True

        if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_p:
            pause = False

    while pause:
        #running = False
        pause = True   
        red = (255,0,0)

        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,500))
        screen.fill((0,0,0))

        my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 50)
        my_font_two = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 10)

        text1 = myfont.render("Pause!", 100, red)
        text2 = myfont.render("Please restart the game", 100, red)

        screen.blit(text2, (10, 200))
        screen.blit(text1, (230, 100))

        pygame.display.update()

        for ev in e:
            if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pause = False
            if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pause = False      
            if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_p:
                pause = True
```

Comment: Is the desired behavior to use a combination "KEYDOWN+ESC" to unpause the game?

Comment: I am trying to close my pause advice.When I press the key p the pause window appears but if I want to close the pause window it doesn't close

Comment: But based on your code, your key event to un-pause uses Escape, not P: ```ev.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:   pause = False ``` Since your code only checks for KEYDOWN events, it would seem that the game will unpause while holding down Escape, which might cause issues since escape also quits the game.

Comment: But it doesn't matter if I changes K_ESCAPE to pause = True. The game is paused when I press the key p anyway.

Comment: What happens if you hold down ESC key while on pause?

Comment: If the game is paused, then the state of `pause` is set `pause = True` when *p* is pressed. Is that intended?

Comment: if I hold down ESC key while on pause nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

The pause screen is displayed in a separate application loop. You've to get the events in that loop, too. Note, in your code, the content of `e` never changes in the "pause" loop:

```py
def checkquit(e):
    global running
    running = True
    pause = False
    for ev in e:
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit(0)
            running = True
        if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            quit(0)
            running = True
        if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_p:
            pause = True

    while pause:

        # [...]


        # get the new events
        e = pygame.event.get()

        # handle the events in the loop
        for ev in e:
            if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pause = False
            if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pause = False      
            if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_p:
                pause = True
```

`runnung` seems to be a variable in global namespace. You've to use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) to change its state.
Furthermore it is superfluous to recreate the window surface in the "pause" loop.

<s>`screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,500))`</s>

---

I recommend to change the game process. Use 1 application loop. e.g.:

```py
myfont=pygame.font.SysFont("monospace",50)
myfonttwo=pygame.font.SysFont("monospace",10)
text1=myfont.render("Pause!",100,red)
text2=myfont.render("Please restart the game",100,red)

def checkquit(e):
    global running, pause
    for ev in e:
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit(0)
            running = True
        if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            if pause:
                pause = False
            else:
                quit(0)
                running = True
        if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_p:
            pause = not pause

running, pause = True, False
while running:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    checkquit(events)

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    if pause:
        # draw pause screen
        screen.blit(text2,(10,200))
        screen.blit(text1,(230,100))

    else:
        # draw game
        # [...]

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

I editet my code to this one:

def checkquit(e):
    running = True
    pause = False
    for ev in e:
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit(0)
            running = False
            pause = False

```
    if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
        quit(0)
        running = False
        pause = False

    if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_p:
            pause = True
            running = False



while pause: 
    pause = True
    red = (255,0,0)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    myfont=pygame.font.SysFont("monospace",50)
    myfonttwo=pygame.font.SysFont("monospace",10)
    myfonttwo=pygame.font.SysFont("monospace",10)
    text1=myfont.render("Pause!",100,red)
    text2=myfont.render("Please resume your game!",100,red)
    text3=myfont.render("Game starts in 10 seconds!",100,red)
    screen.blit(text2,(50,200))
    screen.blit(text1,(300,100))
    screen.blit(text3,(0,300))

    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(4500)
    if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_p:
        pause = False
```

And it works very good! Thanks for your advices!

Comment: Do you know how I can publish pictures about the code's result?

Comment: If someone is interested to see my whole code just  check up my username zerokrezan by github